# Complex generic async return type fails to infer specific return values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

In this playground, I am trying to make a generalized API handler helper that ensures common response types and also leverages inference so that our application code can exhaustively handle all possible scenarios:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgKQM4QHbAGbAIYBGANgKYA0cAgqgJ4YDGASiTAK5QYAqNYJcAvnGxQIIOACIYPEgFpsJVDHEBuAFChIsOAC8KSAFoQAJt16UMNAUJFjx24ytWqpvFOiy5CpAMr0AFiQgeAA8vgFBcCQAHjAkGEaoOgB0hibS5jQAfHAAvKpwycAY8lCh-oF42dGx8YlomDj4xHwA-HBhFXAAXHAYJABuJFBq6hixUNh49HzerPTTqKjMqJAYqCTBnAAieDB4kTFxCW4Nns1wAD5wrPEkuH1G2Qj5cKhzC6g9MFCsJC9GuzwLR620Bqn4o3Gk2mcAAolARFBlqt1pt4YiAMLGPjVI6JRRQIoAcwonHR0B2ewONWO9Q8TVIl2ut3uJEeiBeb3mCk%20QjwRHWZBe9GxIPJUCxRj%20BSGiOBcDJCIpYIhqmwN3oMGAmDgQQA1iRKGBgAAJPDxUilF6cACSGDArBgHQiuNqcFSpkNFiFBRFa3gnFm3MWyMw62pePa7x5obWGzpjS8JEyFGFYYD4tj4ddx0zChRGwJxIoCbOpEyqkyAAoXkUHU7ykEeqWGSRnSFbfbHe2Uy8-OajJaelW646etokkUSps7fWewBKXLZAAKNmAqMD0ZD%20bDfCuisRWeTqnnX2kEGwcH7FqGHIKUBY7AwcBHXZgPRueowEAA7hhFzk2TXoOQyvnOjZ4EkYB4FA6xgY687zmoqp%20oocB4MaZo3lAuS6ngBpGqaA6WlWE4QAQABWJCalWCD8POFB4LQDAvgBTy1peVYALK7H4SRQAOohVou2QAAxJAArIuzwFPej4cIgXIfD0kwCuQcAilKPSSBAEBwAQwBEuI-BqAUggkGpcA4C%20PEwHxAnxEJIlwOJUl3rJD5sApCBKTyXw-OpAJ7D0CDYLp2kEDBxkQmZLyeU%20ilbryqmChpooSDAumvEERBEMZyHzk4AD0RVwHZCh8PyRCRPE1xgHAECDFARCWEScRDPyqglVeEDGhgRJCNAiBhRAEVRYIBCOnAbXwC2SbONIrxJUeuGwjEAmasE1B0Ew8lcNIwQuCQF7oZhxFDCmiXBry3y-PwFZHZESpIjucaretUwwFtzG7V5%2028Id56XhhRHYZdPlJSp-LrPdC2uJpfA5E9h6vesADa4gI%20IAC6yhwN1fi9cSg04TpekGUZTJk9lVXiBQRSKCQeBGNNLCvN8xJAA)

But the result is that inference fails to figure out how to infer these generics. Anyone have tips on how to restructure this to achieve more useful inference? Thanks!

```
import { Jsonifiable, AsyncReturnType } from "type-fest";
import z, { ZodTypeAny } from "zod";

type JsonifiableSchema<Schema extends z.ZodTypeAny> =
  z.infer<Schema> extends Jsonifiable ? Schema : never;

interface SuccessResponse<TData extends Jsonifiable | undefined> {
  success: true
  data?: TData
}
interface ErrorResponse<TErrorCode extends string, TErrorData extends Jsonifiable | undefined> {
  success: false,
  code: TErrorCode
  error?: TErrorData
}

function makeApiHandler<
  TInputSchema extends ZodTypeAny,
  const TSuccessResponse extends SuccessResponse<Jsonifiable>, 
  const TErrorResponse extends ErrorResponse<string, Jsonifiable>
>(
  inputSchema: JsonifiableSchema<TInputSchema>,
  handler: (input: z.infer<TInputSchema>) => Promise<TSuccessResponse | TErrorResponse>
): typeof handler {
  return (input: unknown) => handler(inputSchema.parse(input));
}

const apiHandler = makeApiHandler(z.object({}), async () => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return {success: false, code: "too big"};
  } else if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return {success: true, data: {foo: "bar"}}
  }
  return {success: false, code: "too small"};
})

// these all end up overly general
// hoping for {foo: "bar"} but get Jsonifiable
type successResponse = Extract<AsyncReturnType<typeof apiHandler>, {success: true}>
type errorResponse = Extract<AsyncReturnType<typeof apiHandler>, {success: false}>
type code = errorResponse["code"]; // hoping for "too big" | "too small", instead get string
```

Answer (score 1):

Use type parameters to represent each type argument to success/error response types instead of having a type parameter to represent each as a whole. It makes inferring the types a lot easier for the compiler.

```
function makeApiHandler<
  TInputSchema extends ZodTypeAny,
  const TSuccessData extends Jsonifiable,
  const TErrorCode extends string,
  const TErrorData extends Jsonifiable,
>(
  inputSchema: JsonifiableSchema<TInputSchema>,
  handler: (input: z.infer<TInputSchema>) => Promise<SuccessResponse<TSuccessData> | ErrorResponse<TErrorCode, TErrorData>>
): typeof handler {
  return (input: unknown) => handler(inputSchema.parse(input));
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=true&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgKQM4QHbAGbAIYBGANgKYA0cAgqgJ4YDGASiTAK5QYAqNYJcAvnGxQIIOACIYPEgFpsJVDHEBuAFChIsOAC8KSAFoQAJt16UMNAUJFjx24ytWqpvFOiy5CpAMr0AFiQgeAA8vgFBcCQAHjAkGEaoOgB0hibS5jQAfHAAvKpwycAY8lCh-oF42dGx8YlomDj4xHwA-HBhFXAAXHAYJABuJFBq6hixUNh49HzerPTTqKjMqJAYqCTBnAAieDB4kTFxCW4Nns1wAD5wrPEkuH1G2Qj5cKhzC6g9MFCsJC9GuzwLR620Bqn4o3Gk2mcAAolARFBlqt1pt4YiAMLGPjVI6JRRQIoAcwonHR0B2ewONWO9Q8TVIl2ut3uJEeiBeb3mCk+QjwRHWZBe9GxIPJUCxRj+BSGiOBcDJCIpYIhqmwN3oMGAmDgQQA1iRKGBgAAJPDxUilF6cACSGDArBgHQiuNqcFSpkNFiFBRFa3gnFm3MWlP2rtp7kaXnIwswigV4slOMOboJxJ9cD98cViND1LxJ3p0aFmQAFC8ig6neUgj06VHms6Qrb7Y6m5kM35zUZLT1S5XHT1tEkiiVNnaq+2AJS5bIABRswFRQY+yLjG0D7x5oeyV3Fa7WG8T2NJ4p3mVUU6+0gg2DgXYtQw5BSgLHYGDg-dbMB6Nz1GAgAB3DAZxybIHx7IYv0nGs8CSMA8CgdZoMdKcpzUVUs3gPBjTNR8oFyXU8ANI1TW7S1S2HCACAAKxITVSwQfgpwoPBaAYT9QKeCs71LABZXY-CSKBu1EUsZ2yAAGJIAFYZ2eAoXzfDhEC5D4ekmAVyEzUUJBgCAIDgAhgCJcR+DUApBBILS4BwT8BJgISRPiMSJLgaS5OfRTXzYFSEDUnkvh+bSAT2HoEGwAyenEAhELMiFLJeHz31UrdFg0-lBR0qVov0wzUCCIgiDMjCpycAB6cq4EchQ+H5IhInia4wDgCBBigIhLCJOIhn5VRKvvCBjQwIkhGgRBIogaLYqgMy4GcaRXjSpYFBRPgcjhGIRM1YJqDoJhlK4aRghcEhbzgHCyPwjtUuDXlvl+fhMjUU7IiVJFVvXQjYS2qYYF29iDt8o7eBOm870uvDIKgG7-OWjKtKel7FpFKVCNlaAD3WABtcRUZIcQAF1lDgAa-CG4kxoIyQDKMkzxCZGn8sKoggA)